# How to coerce a data frame to a vector in tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

My data frame is as follows:

```
structure(list(Keyword = c("Sales", "Info", "Reply", "Service", 
"Accounting", "donotreply"), Class = c("Check", "Send", "Do Not Send", 
"Check", NA, "Do Not Send")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

I am trying to transform the Keywords that are "Do Not Send" into their own vector by piping them into an as.vector. The following is my code thus far:

```
DNSkeywords <- data.frame(read_excel('Keywords List.xlsx', sheet = 'Sheet1', col_names = TRUE)) %>% 
  filter(Class == 'Do Not Send') %>% 
  select(Keyword) %>% 
  as.vector(.$Keyword)
```

My output should simply be the following:

```
c("Reply", "donotreply")
```

Granted, I could write a second line of `DNSkeywords <- as.vector(DNSkeywords$Keyword)`, but I would rather pipe it in. I'm unsure how to utilize the `as.vector()` command inside the tidyverse such that I can select a single column in the tibble.

Comment: Not sure what is the issue.  If I use the dput output and with convenient function `pull` `df1 %>% filter(Class == 'Do Not Send') %>% pull(Keyword)#[1] "Reply"      "donotreply"`

Comment: Perhaps Hadley Wickham wrote his book before this function was released with the dplyr package, because I didn't see it mentioned there.... I'm actually only noticing it now on the dplyr site. Boy do I feel silly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pull` or `pluck` as follows.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat %>%
  filter(Class == 'Do Not Send') %>% 
  pull(Keyword)

dat %>%
  filter(Class == 'Do Not Send') %>% 
  pluck("Keyword")
```

Or just `[[` from base R.

```
dat %>%
  filter(Class == 'Do Not Send') %>% 
  `[[`("Keyword")
```

Or `unlist` if you really want to use `select`, but this one is wordy.

```
dat %>%
  filter(Class == 'Do Not Send') %>% 
  select(Keyword) %>%
  unlist(use.names = FALSE)
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- structure(list(Keyword = c("Sales", "Info", "Reply", "Service", 
                           "Accounting", "donotreply"), Class = c("Check", "Send", "Do Not Send", 
                                                                  "Check", NA, "Do Not Send")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                    -6L))
```